# Does Jekyll process files with no front matter?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/
'Any files with front matter are subject to processing.'

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/
'All blog post files must begin with front matter which is typically used to set a layout or other meta data. '

I seem to have a file with no yaml format front matter - a file with some jekyll tags - https://joekingthethird3.github.io/2019/08/09/test but it still has been 'processed' - variables substituted etc. I am using github. You may laugh at my mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because GitHub Pages auto-loads the `jekyll-optional-front-matter` package as a dependency, your markdown files without a front matter do work on your GitHub Pages hosted site.

https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-optional-front-matter explains why:

> Out of the box, Jekyll requires that any markdown file have YAML front matter (key/value pairs separated by two sets of three dashes) in order to be processed and converted to HTML.
>
> While that behavior may be helpful for large, complex sites, sometimes it's easier to simply add a plain markdown file and have it render without fanfare.
>
> This plugin does just that. Any Markdown file in your site's source will be treated as a Page and rendered as HTML, even if it doesn't have YAML front matter.

Comment: Ok,  - 'if your file is within the _posts directory, you can omit the dashes entirely' - https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-jekyll  - and this file mentions the default undisableable plugins - https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-jekyll-plugins - so, jekyll-optional-front-matter is the culprit as well as github.

Answer (score 2):

Posts in Jekyll are special entities. Their behavior is mostly inconsistent with the rest of Jekyll objects.

To that end, posts will get "processed" by Jekyll **even if they do not have front matter**.
They just need to be a file named following the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD-TITLE.extension` somewhere inside a directory named `_posts` or `_drafts`.

*(This behavior is independent of the `jekyll-optional-front-matter` plugin and can be reproduced with just vanilla Jekyll as well.)*

Comment: not sure that this is correct - the jekyll docs mention this - https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/  - 'All blog post files must begin with front matter which is typically used to set a layout or other meta data.' - they need to be in the name pattern format but on github they don't need front matter in the _post directory.

Comment: You can try it with a fresh jekyll site. Just run `jekyll new test-site` somewhere in your system. Verify that the Gemfile inside `test-site` is pointing to `jekyll-3.8.x` and remove the front matter in the "welcome-to-jekyll" post. When you then build / serve the site, you should see the generated post.